# Model.objects.get returns nothing

Tags: python, django, object, get, models

I'm having this weird problem when using
`Model.objects.get(op1=1,op2=2)`

it raises the does not exist error although it exists. Did that ever happen with anyone?

I even checked in my logs to make sure that the log happened when the id already existed in the database.

[2015-04-24 20:18:21,106]  ERROR:   Couldn't find the model entry: Traceback (most recent call last):
DoesNotExist: NpBilling matching query does not exist.

and in the database, the last modified date for this row specifically is 20:18:19.

How could that possible ever happen?! The weird thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it throws this error.

I tried to use get_or_create but I end up with 2 entries in the database. one of them is what was already created.

Thanks in advance for your help. I would appreciate fast responses and suggestions.

Comment: It's telling you you don't have an object matching `op1=1, op2=2`. Are you sure that you do in fact have one that matches? How are you determining that?

Comment: logs time is after the time of creation and modification of the row in the database.. besides,, if i use get_or_create it creates it.. and i end up with 2 rows.

Comment: Maybe a race condition?

Comment: op1 and op2 are both integers right?

Comment: op1 and op2 are integers..

Comment: Can you get the object using Model.objects.filter(op1=1,op2=2)[0]

Comment: please provide some more info/code/context

Comment: race condition.. well yes.. it could be but i already override the save function of this model to save in it the created date and last modified date.. the last modified date is always before the error according to the time that is shown in the logs.

Comment: you do not need to do it, btw, django can do it for you, e.g. `field = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, ...)`

Comment: race condition is not handled automatically in django with a lock or anything?!

Comment: Can you get the model using each query individually with GET, also can you get it with filter instead of get?

Comment: i can do it with filter sure.. and take the 1st obj in the list.

Comment: what do you mean by each query individually?

Comment: I mean do you either get something back or multiple if you run:

Model.objects.get(op1=1)

or

Model.objects.get(op2=2)

Comment: You'll have to provide more code, there really isn't enough info to see what could be going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using transaction.commit() before my second query.